# Motivation: Stochastic Interest rate model

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-volatility, models

what is a reason that someone might be interested in a stochastic-interest model such as the Chen model?
Also can you provide me with a link to an easy to read motivational paper/part of a paper on the subject?

Thanks

Comment: We do not yet know the Chen model. It would help if you can provide more details.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chen_model

Answer (score 1):

[Chan, Karolyi, Longstaff, and Sanders (1992)](http://personal.anderson.ucla.edu/francis.longstaff/empiricalcomparison.pdf) compares empirically the performance of the main interest rates model.

The first page also provides the main references on those models.